# Gem like tario/shikashi for jRuby

Tags: sinatra, jruby

Previously I was using MRI Ruby now I am moving to jRuby. Most of the gems I am using are compatible with jRuby. But the gem [shikashi](https://github.com/tario/shikashi) is incompatible with jRuby.

I will be thankful if any one provide the best alternative or work around.